# How can I make this UILabel accessible to other classes?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a class which is a viewcontroller and it contains:

```
-(void)testNSTimer
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{ self.view.welcomeBackLabel alpha = 0;} //welcomeBackLabel does not exist.
                     completion:nil];
}
```

However welcomeBackLabel is not available in this circumstance because it is created in the controller's view AKA self.view as shown in the following code:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        welcomeBackLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, -20, 100, 120)]; //welcomeBackLabel is not available for other classes to use, but I want it to be.
        [welcomeBackLabel setText:@"Welcome"];
        [welcomeBackLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        UIFont *welcomeFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:20];
        welcomeBackLabel.font = welcomeFont;
        [welcomeBackLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [welcomeBackLabel setAlpha:0.65];
        [self addSubview:welcomeBackLabel];
    }
```

I created a property however it is not detected by the viewcontroller's class even after importing the view's .h file. Can anybody should me the various ways I could have welcomeBackLabel be usable in my controller class?

EDIT:

For example, in my view's .h I have:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UILabel *welcomeBackLabel;
```

and I have

```
#import "view.h"
```

in my controller.m but its not detecting it as a usable property o.o

EDIT2:

Ok so if I have HomeScreenView *testView = [[HomeScreenView alloc]init]; then YES i can use the property fine ala testView.welcomebackLabel.etc . It just does not work when I have set the view for the controller using [self setView:testView] and then use self.view.welcomeBackLabel... Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a UIViewController, self.view is returned as a UIView. If you "know" that it is a particular subclass of UIView, you need to cast it so you can access methods from the subclass. You could inline this, but for clarity:

```
MyUIView *v = self.view;
[v myMethod];
```

Or if you want inline:

```
[(MyUIView *) self.view myMethod];
```

If it is *sometimes* the right subclass you can test:

```
UIView *v = self.view;
if([v isKindOfClass:[MYUIView class]]) {
    [(MyUIView *) self.view myMethod];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, what I am trying to do is keep events in my viewcontroller and the drawing/controls in my view classes, how would you do it? Just want to know the general ways I can go about doing this, like should I continue to typecast or do it as explained in my second edit, etc.

Comment: If you are going to call lots of your own methods on the view, which is not unreasonable, you might want to give your UIViewController a member MyUIView *myView. You can even make a custom setter so that [myViewController setMyView:v] also sets the view property as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create an @property in the .h file of your class and it should be accessible from other classes well.

Comment: Then self.view.welcomeBackLabel should be usable, correct? As that is not happening for me. To clarify, the view is set correctly for the controller so that is not a problem.

Comment: Yes, you'll of course have to change `welcomeBackLabel` in your code excerpt to `self.welcomeBackLabel`

Comment: Yes I have done that (or alternatively _welcomeBackLabel), however the problem is that the controller does not see it. so using self.view.welcomeBackLabel does not work.

Comment: Try to put breakpoints to ensure that the label is being initialised before the control comes to the animation.

Comment: The issue is shown before I compile. The error is Property 'welcomeBackLabel" not found on object of type 'UIView *'

Comment: What is the type of the UIView subclass in which you're adding `welcomeBackLabel`? Type cast the self.view to that class type and you should now be able to use it.

Comment: Take a look at my last edit, I think its clearer now as to what is going on.